# How to replace specific string values for several files in R?

Tags: r, string, dplyr, data.table

I have 50 files (each with 1 million - 2 million rows) all with a `variant_id` column I want to make changes to - the files all have a layout like this:

```
variant_id                    ...
chr1_665098_G_A_b38           ...
chr2_665097_C_T_b38           ...
chr3_665094_A_GG_b38          ...
chr10_23458_TTTCAAG_C_b38     ...
```

I want to edit the `variant_id` column to become:

```
variant_id
1:665098
2:665097
3:665094
10:23458
```

I am trying to make this change to all my files at the same time by:

```
#Read in all files
temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], fread(temp[i]))

#Edit variant_id strings for every dataset in environment
my_func <- function(x) {
  x <- x %>%
    select(variant_id, pval_nominal) %>%
    mutate(variant_id = sub("^([^-]*-[^-]*).*", "\\1", variant_id))
}

e <- .GlobalEnv
nms <- ls(pattern = ".txt$", envir = e)
for(nm in nms) e[[nm]] <- my_func(e[[nm]])
```

I am stuck on the `mutate(variant_id = sub("^([^-]*-[^-]*).*", "\\1", variant_id))` - with not knowing how best to use `sub` to implement all the changes I need with `chr` being removed, the first `_` becoming a `:` and then having all characters after the 2nd numeric value being removed. How can I get this working? Is there a better function to try? Any help is appreciated.

Input example data:

```
df <- structure(list(variant_id = c("chr1_665098_G_A_b38", "chr2_665097_C_T_b38", 
"chr3_665094_A_GG_b38", "chr10_23458_TTTCAAG_C_b38\xca")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to capture the characters and replace with the backreference of the captured groups

```
library(data.table)
df[, variant_id := sub("chr(\\d+)_(\\d+)_.*", "\\1:\\2", variant_id)]
```

-output

```
> df
   variant_id
1:   1:665098
2:   2:665097
3:   3:665094
4:   10:23458
```

---

If it is more than one file, read the files in a `list`, and keep it in the `list`

```
lst1 <- lapply(temp, function(x) fread(x)[,
    variant_id := sub("chr(\\d+)_(\\d+)_.*", "\\1:\\2", variant_id)][])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fully reproducible example of your situation.

The goal here is to show you not only another possible solution for your regex, but also an alternative way to set up your code.

I noticed that in your function you are selecting 2 specific columns, so I added that option in my code.

```r
# reproducible example
df <- data.frame(variant_id = c("chr1_665098_G_A_b38", "chr2_665097_C_T_b38", 
                                "chr3_665094_A_GG_b38", "chr10_23458_TTTCAAG_C_b38\xca"),
                 pval_nominal = c(0.005,0.01),
                 filler = letters[1:2])
folder <- tempdir()
write.csv(df, file.path(folder, "test1.txt"))
write.csv(df, file.path(folder, "test2.txt"))
```

```r
# library
library(data.table)

# read all files: use full paths! you'll avoid a lot of issues
temp <- list.files(folder, pattern = "*.txt", full.names = TRUE)

# read files with lappply and make a list of them!
l <- lapply(temp, fread, sep = ",")

# select columns and modify variant_id
# if you use data.table you generally want to stick with it and not to mix it with dplyr and viceversa (but that depends on you)
l <- lapply(l, function(d) d[,.(variant_id = sub("^\\D+(\\d+)_(\\d+).*", "\\1:\\2", variant_id), pval_nominal)])
l
#> [[1]]
#>    variant_id pval_nominal
#> 1:   1:665098        0.005
#> 2:   2:665097        0.010
#> 3:   3:665094        0.005
#> 4:   10:23458        0.010
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    variant_id pval_nominal
#> 1:   1:665098        0.005
#> 2:   2:665097        0.010
#> 3:   3:665094        0.005
#> 4:   10:23458        0.010
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>